# Is it possible to repeat a geometry pattern along the lenght of a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

i was adding some deformation to a curve i made on Blender with Zbrush, but the curve is too long, so i wanted to know if its possible to export (just the part) of the curve that i deformed, and then somehow repeat that geometry like a pattern (with geomety, not texture) alongside the Blender curve. (i can export the .obj of the already deformed part of the curve, then import it into blender)

[image]

Comment: You could theoretically use an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier to do that.

Comment: Ok, Ill try, thank you!
But do i have to create a new curve then?

Comment: No, not necessarily. You may need to remove the Bevel Depth value though.

Comment: Posting your .blend file can help us make Specific instructions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use and array, then curve modifier. You start by adding the array, making it the length you wan't. Then add the curve modifier, and select the curve as the object

[image]

Comment: How did you know :-0

Comment: Do i need to create a new curve in order to do that?

Comment: No, you can use the one you have...

Comment: You just need to make sure it is still a curve, and the sculpted bit is a mesh

Comment: Oh...wait, do i need to make the 'special geometry' on Zbrush rect or curve? because the curve isnt like a rect line..

Comment: You importeded it into blender right?